# How do I tell git to include my merge commits when doing a soft reset?

Tags: git

I often find myself in the case where I want to squash two or more commits from my local repository. My strategy for doing this is to start with a soft reset, then commit all the resetted changes.

For the soft reset, I use the following command:

`git reset --soft HEAD~n`

where n is the number of commits I want to reset. This works fine provided I haven't included merge commits in the number of commits I want to reset - for example, if I committed four times on my current branch and want to soft reset HEAD~4.

However, let's say after my 4 commits, I merge another branch onto my current branch. Git implicitly commits the merge changes and it shows when I do a git log. Now, if I want to do a soft reset back to HEAD~5 (4 commits + the merge commit), git will ignore the merge commit and reset the next latest non-merge commit, in addition to the 4 commits I intended to reset. Essentially, I should reset back HEAD~4 - git seems to ignore merge commits when doing a reset.

Why does Git behave this way? And how can I include these merge commits in the soft reset?

(Let's take an example : I have commits A-B-C-D-E-F in chronological order, F being a merge commit.  *git reset --soft HEAD~4* will reset the branch to A: commits BCDE are reset, commit F is not included in the 4.)

Comment: But when you reset to `HEAD~5` (4 commits + the merge commit), then the merge commit is *not* ignored, because it is the 5th commit. Is your real problem that you want have the 4 commits squashed together into a single commit and then have a merge commit on top of that? You can't achieve this with `git reset` alone.

Comment: I didn't express myself clearly enough - in the HEAD~5 case, the merge commit *is* ignored, and only the next 5 non-merging commits will be taken. Say you have commits A-B-C-D-E-F, in chronological order, with F being a merge commit: reset HEAD~4 will reset commits BCDE. Interestingly, actually, F is "cancelled" in this case: it doesn't appear anymore, but isn't counted in the number of commits you reset.

Comment: I tried it. A branch pointed to F (a merge commit); then after `reset HEAD~4` it pointed to B. That is the correct behavior. Do you observe something different?

Comment: After your edit, you describe a different observation that does not match my expectations. Further details would be required to diagnose the situation. For example, the output of `git log --graph --oneline F` (truncated to, say, ten lines, which should include A and only few commits of the merged side branch).

Comment: What is your git version? It seems this behavior cannot be reproduced in my version (2.18.0)

Comment: Can you also post the outputs of git log / git reflog

Comment: You need to be aware that the `~` and `^` suffixes operate on the *commit graph*. I recommend working through http://think-like-a-git.net/ here.

Comment: @ChrisNeve please check my answer. I tried to explain this behavior.

Comment: All right, my bad. I tested again and this time the behaviour was even more strange and inexplicable, but it didn't seem directly related to merge commits. I assume it's related to merge commits having multiple parents, I'll read up on that to complete my understanding of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not because git ignores the merge commits. It's because how `~` and `^` works in Git.

`~n` means to go up `n levels` in the hierarchy via the first parent.If you give it as `^n`, it means to go to the `n th` parent, starting from the left.

If we run `git log --graph --pretty=oneline` in your git repository (the example you gave), we would possibly have something like:

```
*   da497fa213169e75b9cec382e28561d5e56f6daf (HEAD -> master) f (merge)
|\
| * aaa519bce409d0fb5e187dff6ed82d73d7cd437b (Dev) e
|/
* f537237e48fc7218af288ddc91a02c1e24ea1887 d
* 2c41ee71ee7b9b450cd10eab685e0007fe92b688 c
* 411c96c85a2e34bf798cab5c0e6f4532a5ebfe35 b
* c9d38077a5704df382b0fd0d83d4fcdf7c408f23 a
```

Notice that commit `f` has two parents (due to the merge commit). Now when you say HEAD~4, it will look for 4 commits in its hierarchy after HEAD, from left, which will be `b`. (It will not take `e`, because it's in the `second parent` of `f`.)

You can use `git rev-parse` command to resolve and get the particular commit id.

For an example: if you run, `git rev-parse HEAD~4`, you will see it returns the commit id of `a`.

In my opinion, you don't need to worry about this as ultimately, git will reset your branch to the given commit id. But in case, say, you want to reset your branch to commit `e`, now you need to tell it the right way to access it.

So you can tell it, select the second parent of HEAD, and reset to that.

That would be equal to: HEAD^2

You could also expand it to reach `a` through `e`, if you give your reset command as:

`git reset --soft HEAD^2~3`.

But in my opinion, this is not required in your case.

Here's a good representation for the above, taken from the git `rev-parse` documentation.

```
G   H   I   J
 \ /     \ /
  D   E   F
   \  |  / \
    \ | /   |
     \|/    |
      B     C
       \   /
        \ /
         A

A =      = A^0
B = A^   = A^1     = A~1
C = A^2  = A^2
D = A^^  = A^1^1   = A~2
E = B^2  = A^^2
F = B^3  = A^^3
G = A^^^ = A^1^1^1 = A~3
H = D^2  = B^^2    = A^^^2  = A~2^2
I = F^   = B^3^    = A^^3^
J = F^2  = B^3^2   = A^^3^2
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse/1.8.0#_specifying_revisions

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much. As I mentioned in previous comment, after testing again I was unable to find direct correlation with merge commits, so I'm confident your link will help me understand the difference between the observed and the expected.